# Django - Raw SQL Queries - What Happens in Joins

Tags: django, django-models

I'm reading that I can [use raw SQL in Django and have Django actually build my models from the result](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)s.

However I'm wondering what happens if I use joins in the raw SQL.  How will Django know what models to use?

(Are there any other issues I should be aware of?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the joins that matter, but the column names. You could, for example, do the following:

```
SELECT table.id, other_table.name AS name from table join other_table using (id)
```

and pass that into your `table` model. Django would then treat the names from `other_table` as though they were names from `table` and give your normal `table` instances. I can't imagine why you would want to do that though...

The important thing to remember is that Django is using a very simple mapping from your SQL to its model structure. You can subvert it if you want, but you'll probably end up with some hard to maintain code.

Comment: That page I linked to says it uses the table name to find which model to use.  So I'm wondering if I'm joining the tables from two different models how would it know which model to use?

Comment: I don't think that it says that. You pass the query to ModelName.objects.raw(query), so you get back ModelName objects. What it does say is that the table name you need to use in the raw SQL is create as appname_modelname.

Comment: So if I do a join in the raw query, are the joined table fields essentially like fields that have been added to the model (from which the query was executed) via `annotate()`? Note, I am here because my query spans a many-to-many relationship and my search term is for the related table, and I'm looking for a way to only receive composite records that match that term. The reason I'm here is because we've constructed an advanced search interface for multiple composite views composed on 6 or 7 tables each, and searches on the M:M tables produces records that don't match the search terms.

Comment: And also, in the raw query, how do I refer to linking tables? Those are obfuscated from the ORM.